# Chrome clear cache extension - when run cache is not cleared immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a very specific chrome extension to clear the browser cache and reload the page. I did this because I tried virtually all clear cache extensions in Google Store and none worked.

The problem is that I need to click three times until the cache is cleared. Any ideas why?

This is the extension:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Clear Cache",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Clear Cache",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Clear Cache",
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

 "permissions": [ "browsingData" ]
}
```

background.js:

```
function clearMe () {

    // clears cache
    var ms = (30 * 60) * 1000; // 30 minutes
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - ms;
    chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": time});

    // reloads page 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
    });

}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(clearMe);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`chrome.browsingData.removeCache`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData#method-removeCache) method is asynchronous (i.e. non-blocking). This means that if you immediately reload the tab after calling `removeCache`, the `removeCache` call is still being processed and the cache may not be empty yet.

To get the desired behavior, wait until the cache is cleared, by putting the `reload` call in the callback to `removeCache`. And by the way, you don't need to call `chrome.tabs.getSelected` to get the current tab, just use the `tab` parameter that is passed in to the [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event.

```
function clearMe(tab) {
    var ms = (30 * 60) * 1000; // 30 minutes
    var time = Date.now() - ms;
    chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": time}, function() {
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(clearMe);
```